# Where is scanf() reading input from, if not from the keyboard?

Tags: c, eclipse, keyboard, mingw, scanf

I'm a novice programmer getting introduced to C and I'm missing something fundamental about the way my scanf() works. I want to read a single int from the keyboard with code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int userBookSelection;
    scanf("%i", &userBookSelection);
    printf("Printing userBookSelection: %i", userBookSelection);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run the code, the console stays black until I stop debugging. There is never a cursor waiting for keyboard input. When I stop debug I can see this output in the console, same every time:

Printing userBookSelection: 2130567168

I'm debugging in Eclipse with MinGW GCC compiler on Windows. The code syntax seems to be correct -- is it possible there's something wrong in my build path to make this happen? I need to know why scanf() isn't reading for keyboard input.

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: It works as intended when I run your code

Comment: The program as shown is correct ISO C (up to a point: `scanf` is broken-as-specified, and should never be used in production -- but for this kind of learning exercise it's fine) and should work as intended.  _Exactly_ what compiler, debugger, console, operating system, etc. are you using? Leave nothing out.

Comment: I'm using MinGW GCC compiler in Eclipse, Windows 7.

Comment: scanf() returns a value - you should check it.

Comment: Did you try typing a number even if there is no blinking cursor?

Comment: I guess this would be regarded as a console-mode program, and you need a console to run it in. I don't know much about Eclipse -- are you generating a .exe file and then running it in a DOS Box? Or relying on Eclipse to run the code when it's built? If Eclipse runs it, does it pop up a console of some sort? The MINGW gcc will build console-mode programs for Windows, but you do actually need the console.

Answer (score 1):

So I've gotten a line of code from my professor which takes care of this bug -- whether it's a necessary solution particular to Eclipse and/or MinGW I'm not sure. In any case, here's the code with the additional line:

```
int main(void) {
    int userBookSelection;
    setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);//<---The magic line

    scanf("%i", &userBookSelection);
    printf("Printing userBookSelection: %i", userBookSelection);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'd appreciate any additional wisdom on what's going on, what setvbuf() is doing and how scanf() works more fundamentally.

Comment: That must be a quirk of Eclipse, MinGW, and/or Windows "consoles" -- going by only the C specification, applying `setvbuf` to `stdout` should not have any effect on a call to `scanf` (which works only with `stdin`).  I cannot help you any further than that.